# Contain не находит элемент в List

Tags: c#, массивы, циклы, list

Доброго времени суток. Имеется следующий код:

```
            int[] perm = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
            int[] perm_inverse = new int[] { 0, 3, 2, 1};
            List<int[]> listOfCertainPerms = new List<int[]>();
            for (int k = 0; k < perm.Length; k++)
            {
                int[] intTmp = new int[perm.Length];
                int[] intTmp_inverse = new int[perm_inverse.Length];
                for (int j = 0; j < intTmp.Length; j++)
                    intTmp[j] = (perm[j] + k) % perm.Length;
                listOfCertainPerms.Add(intTmp);
                for (int j = 0; j < intTmp.Length; j++)
                    intTmp_inverse[j] = (perm_inverse[j] + k) % perm.Length;
                listOfCertainPerms.Add(intTmp_inverse);
            }
            if (listOfCertainPerms.Contains(perm))
                Console.WriteLine("Success!");
```

Содержимое `listOfContains` после выполнения данного кода следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако почему-то условие `if`не выполняется, хотя массив `perm` - это самый первый элемент в `listOfCertainPerms`. Помогите разобраться, в чём дело.

Comment: А почему у вас `perm_inverse` с нуля начинается, когда он якобы должен быть инвертирован?

Comment: Массивы сравниваются по ссылкам, а не по содержимому. Объекты `perm` и `intTmp`, выделенный на очередной итерации цикла, ссылаются на разные участки памяти и, соответственно, не равны.

Comment: @Vlad надо бы ваш комментарий как ответ сделать.

Comment: @Bulson, ну он "инвертирован" по другим соображениям. Насчёт предложения сделать как ответ, полностью согласен. Хочу посмотреть, как по значению искать в листе.

Comment: Ну тогда `LINQ` наше все по работе с коллекциями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Массивы сравниваются по ссылке, а не по содержимому.

```
var a = new[] {1};
var b = new[] {1};
// a != b, т.к. a и b указывают на разные участки памяти
```

Для сравнения массивов по содержимому можно использовать метод [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx). В приведенном примере `a.SequenceEqual(b) == true`.

Для поиска в коллекции можно воспользоваться методом [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = listOfCertainPerms.Any(_ => _.SequenceEqual(perm));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Совсем забыл про `Any`.